# How to remove sorting from some columns devextreme-reactive react grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

Is it possible to remove sorting from some columns devextreme-reactive react grid?

I am using the following grids: https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/sorting/

You can try code over here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1ir3k

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import {
  SortingState,
  IntegratedSorting,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid';
import {
  Grid,
  Table,
  TableHeaderRow,
} from '@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui';


import { generateRows } from '../../../demo-data/generator';

export default () => {
  const [columns] = useState([
    { name: 'name', title: 'Name' },
    { name: 'gender', title: 'Gender' },
    { name: 'city', title: 'City' },
    { name: 'car', title: 'Car' },
  ]);
  const [rows] = useState(generateRows({ length: 8 }));
  const [defaultSorting] = useState([
    { columnName: 'gender', direction: 'desc' },
  ]);
  const [sortingStateColumnExtensions] = useState([
    { columnName: 'gender', sortingEnabled: false },
  ]);

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Grid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
      >
        <SortingState
          defaultSorting={defaultSorting}
          columnExtensions={sortingStateColumnExtensions}
        />
        <IntegratedSorting />
        <Table />
        <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```